# Insert PHP code inside of PrettyPhoto.js file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

im trying to add a piece of php code inside of prettyphoto.js

Here is a piece of the code that im working with, where i need to add the php code is where the ((CODE ME HERE)) is at

(function($) {
    $.prettyPhoto = {version: '3.1.6'};

```
$.fn.prettyPhoto = function(pp_settings) {
    pp_settings = jQuery.extend({
        hook: 'rel', /* the attribute tag to use for prettyPhoto hooks. default: 'rel'. For HTML5, use "data-rel" or similar. */
        animation_speed: 'normal', /* fast/slow/normal */
        ajaxcallback: function() {},
        slideshow: 5000, /* false OR interval time in ms */
        autoplay_slideshow: false, /* true/false */
        opacity: 0.80, /* Value between 0 and 1 */
        show_title: true, /* true/false */
        allow_resize: true, /* Resize the photos bigger than viewport. true/false */
        allow_expand: true, /* Allow the user to expand a resized image. true/false */
        default_width: 500,
        default_height: 344,
        counter_separator_label: '/', /* The separator for the gallery counter 1 "of" 2 */
        theme: 'pp_default', /* light_rounded / dark_rounded / light_square / dark_square / facebook */
        horizontal_padding: 20, /* The padding on each side of the picture */
        hideflash: false, /* Hides all the flash object on a page, set to TRUE if flash appears over prettyPhoto */
        wmode: 'opaque', /* Set the flash wmode attribute */
        autoplay: true, /* Automatically start videos: True/False */
        modal: false, /* If set to true, only the close button will close the window */
        deeplinking: true, /* Allow prettyPhoto to update the url to enable deeplinking. */
        overlay_gallery: true, /* If set to true, a gallery will overlay the fullscreen image on mouse over */
        overlay_gallery_max: 30, /* Maximum number of pictures in the overlay gallery */
        keyboard_shortcuts: true, /* Set to false if you open forms inside prettyPhoto */
        changepicturecallback: function(){}, /* Called everytime an item is shown/changed */
        callback: function(){}, /* Called when prettyPhoto is closed */
        ie6_fallback: true,
        markup: '<div class="pp_pic_holder"> \
                    <div class="ppt"> </div> \
                    <div class="pp_top"> \
                        <div class="pp_left"></div> \
                        <div class="pp_middle"></div> \
                        <div class="pp_right"></div> \
                    </div> \
                    <div class="pp_content_container"> \
                        <div class="pp_left"> \
                        <div class="pp_right"> \
                            <div class="pp_content"> \
                                <div class="pp_loaderIcon"></div> \
                                <div class="pp_fade"> \
                                    <a href="#" class="pp_expand" title="Expand the image">Expand</a> \
                                    <div class="pp_hoverContainer"> \
                                        <a class="pp_next" href="#">next</a> \
                                        <a class="pp_previous" href="#">previous</a> \
                                    </div> \
                                    <div id="pp_full_res"></div> \
                                    <div class="pp_details"> \
                                        <div class="pp_nav"> \
                                            <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_previous">Previous</a> \
                                            <p class="currentTextHolder">0/0</p> \
                                            <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_next">Next</a> \
                                        </div> \
                                        <p class="pp_description"></p> \
                                        <div class="pp_social">{pp_social}</div> \
                                        <a class="pp_close" href="#">Close</a> \
                                    </div> \
                                </div> \
                            </div> \
                        </div> \
                        </div> \
                    </div> \
                    <div class="pp_bottom"> \
                        <div class="pp_left"></div> \
                        <div class="pp_middle"></div> \
                        <div class="pp_right"></div> \
                    </div> \
                </div> \
                <div class="pp_overlay"></div>',
        gallery_markup: '<div class="pp_gallery"> \
                            <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_previous">Previous</a> \
                            <div> \
                                <ul> \
                                    {gallery} \
                                </ul> \
                            </div> \
                            <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_next">Next</a> \
                        </div> ((CODE ME HERE))',
        image_markup: '<img id="fullResImage" src="{path}" />',
        flash_markup: '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="{width}" height="{height}"><param name="wmode" value="{wmode}" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="{path}" /><embed src="{path}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="{width}" height="{height}" wmode="{wmode}"></embed></object>',
        quicktime_markup: '<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="{height}" width="{width}"><param name="src" value="{path}"><param name="autoplay" value="{autoplay}"><param name="type" value="video/quicktime"><embed src="{path}" height="{height}" width="{width}" autoplay="{autoplay}" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"></embed></object>',
        iframe_markup: '<iframe src ="{path}" width="{width}" height="{height}" onload="setTimeout(resizeIframe);" frameborder="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
        inline_markup: '<div class="pp_inline">{content}</div>',
        custom_markup: '',
        social_tools: '<div class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div><div class="facebook"><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&href={location_href}&layout=button_count&show_faces=true&width=500&action=like&font&colorscheme=light&height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>' /* html or false to disable */
    }, pp_settings);
```

and the code i need to add is below.

" data-color-override="#DA1010" data-hover-color-override="false" data-hover-text-color-override="#fff" style="visibility: visible; background-color: rgb(218, 16, 16);">Visit Page

Everytime i keep trying to tweak it to make it work the pages go white.
im using the wordpress plugin called Advanced Custom Fields if it helps.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: By default, your web server would NOT run the PHP preprocessor on .js files. You would need to direct your webserver to process .js files in order to do so. Alternatively, you could have stored this code in a .php file and ensure that the headers produce a javascript data type. Your script src would then point to this .php file. Yet another alternative is to store your processed PHP output as a javascript variable in the php page that is loading this javascript file. Then you can just concatenate that variable instead.

Comment: Hmmm, ok.   So the way that im thinking of doing it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

As in most webservers  (and by default), .js files are not processed by PHP.

Therefore, PHP code placed inside your .js files will be output as is in its raw code form.

One alternative is to place the PHP code inside the page and store it in a JavaScript variable from which you are loading the .js file. Then, use that variable in your .js file.

Here's an example:

**index.php**

```
<?php
echo('<script>var processedData = "' + '" data-color-override="#DA1010" data-hover-color-override="false" data-hover-text-color-override="#fff" style="visibility: visible; background-color: rgb(218, 16, 16);">Visit Page' + '";</script>');
echo('<script src="prettyphoto.js"></script>');
?>
```

**prettyphoto.js**

```
$.fn.prettyPhoto = function(pp_settings) {
    pp_settings = jQuery.extend({
        hook: 'rel', /* the attribute tag to use for prettyPhoto hooks. default: 'rel'. For HTML5, use "data-rel" or similar. */
        animation_speed: 'normal', /* fast/slow/normal */
        ajaxcallback: function() {},
        slideshow: 5000, /* false OR interval time in ms */
        autoplay_slideshow: false, /* true/false */
        opacity: 0.80, /* Value between 0 and 1 */
        show_title: true, /* true/false */
        allow_resize: true, /* Resize the photos bigger than viewport. true/false */
        allow_expand: true, /* Allow the user to expand a resized image. true/false */
        default_width: 500,
        default_height: 344,
        counter_separator_label: '/', /* The separator for the gallery counter 1 "of" 2 */
        theme: 'pp_default', /* light_rounded / dark_rounded / light_square / dark_square / facebook */
        horizontal_padding: 20, /* The padding on each side of the picture */
        hideflash: false, /* Hides all the flash object on a page, set to TRUE if flash appears over prettyPhoto */
        wmode: 'opaque', /* Set the flash wmode attribute */
        autoplay: true, /* Automatically start videos: True/False */
        modal: false, /* If set to true, only the close button will close the window */
        deeplinking: true, /* Allow prettyPhoto to update the url to enable deeplinking. */
        overlay_gallery: true, /* If set to true, a gallery will overlay the fullscreen image on mouse over */
        overlay_gallery_max: 30, /* Maximum number of pictures in the overlay gallery */
        keyboard_shortcuts: true, /* Set to false if you open forms inside prettyPhoto */
        changepicturecallback: function(){}, /* Called everytime an item is shown/changed */
        callback: function(){}, /* Called when prettyPhoto is closed */
        ie6_fallback: true,
        markup: '<div class="pp_pic_holder"> \
                    <div class="ppt"> </div> \
                    <div class="pp_top"> \
                        <div class="pp_left"></div> \
                        <div class="pp_middle"></div> \
                        <div class="pp_right"></div> \
                    </div> \
                    <div class="pp_content_container"> \
                        <div class="pp_left"> \
                        <div class="pp_right"> \
                            <div class="pp_content"> \
                                <div class="pp_loaderIcon"></div> \
                                <div class="pp_fade"> \
                                    <a href="#" class="pp_expand" title="Expand the image">Expand</a> \
                                    <div class="pp_hoverContainer"> \
                                        <a class="pp_next" href="#">next</a> \
                                        <a class="pp_previous" href="#">previous</a> \
                                    </div> \
                                    <div id="pp_full_res"></div> \
                                    <div class="pp_details"> \
                                        <div class="pp_nav"> \
                                            <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_previous">Previous</a> \
                                            <p class="currentTextHolder">0/0</p> \
                                            <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_next">Next</a> \
                                        </div> \
                                        <p class="pp_description"></p> \
                                        <div class="pp_social">{pp_social}</div> \
                                        <a class="pp_close" href="#">Close</a> \
                                    </div> \
                                </div> \
                            </div> \
                        </div> \
                        </div> \
                    </div> \
                    <div class="pp_bottom"> \
                        <div class="pp_left"></div> \
                        <div class="pp_middle"></div> \
                        <div class="pp_right"></div> \
                    </div> \
                </div> \
                <div class="pp_overlay"></div>',
        gallery_markup: '<div class="pp_gallery"> \
                            <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_previous">Previous</a> \
                            <div> \
                                <ul> \
                                    {gallery} \
                                </ul> \
                            </div> \
                            <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_next">Next</a> \
                        </div> ' + processedData,
        image_markup: '<img id="fullResImage" src="{path}" />',
        flash_markup: '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="{width}" height="{height}"><param name="wmode" value="{wmode}" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="{path}" /><embed src="{path}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="{width}" height="{height}" wmode="{wmode}"></embed></object>',
        quicktime_markup: '<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="{height}" width="{width}"><param name="src" value="{path}"><param name="autoplay" value="{autoplay}"><param name="type" value="video/quicktime"><embed src="{path}" height="{height}" width="{width}" autoplay="{autoplay}" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"></embed></object>',
        iframe_markup: '<iframe src ="{path}" width="{width}" height="{height}" onload="setTimeout(resizeIframe);" frameborder="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
        inline_markup: '<div class="pp_inline">{content}</div>',
        custom_markup: '',
        social_tools: '<div class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div><div class="facebook"><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&href={location_href}&layout=button_count&show_faces=true&width=500&action=like&font&colorscheme=light&height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>' /* html or false to disable */
    }, pp_settings);
```

Comment: Hmmm.  I will try this.